# jQueryUI Draggable how do I change object inserted into sortable dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dynamic, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am struggling to find the right way to change the object jQuery UI droppable inserts into the target div.

I have been playing with the stop even but I can not figure out how to change the item's html.

It is a complicated piece of html that I am dragging and I need to take it's ID and send it to a factory function and use the received object for the actual insertion rather than the object dragged and dropped.

I am using draggable with sortable and wiring it with the connect to sortable.

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2.

Thanks!!

Here is what the code I have looks like:

```
$(".class").on("dragstop", function (event, ui) {
    var id= ui.helper[0].id;


    var o = $(snippetFactory(id));
   //  I Want "o" to be inserted instead of the object dragged.


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var id= ui.helper[0].id;
var o = $(snippetFactory(id));
ui.item.replaceWith(o);
```

Comment: ui.item is actually the original item that you drag, not then one that you drop.

Answer (score 0):

The event `receive` in the sortable is your friend (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive)

- ui.item refers to the source-object that is draggable.
- ui.helper gives you the dropped object

So you can do

```
$(".selector").sortable({
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    var id= ui.helper[0].id;
    var o = $(snippetFactory(id));
    $(ui.helper[0]).replaceWith(o);
  }
});
```